# Toast on Image Detection in Vuforia either using Unity or Java without C++

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have to Toast a message when an Image is detected.
Which is the easiest way to do?
Using Unity or just using JAVA without native calls?

I've tried all the ways given in the developer.vuforia.com site

I've tried
1. How To Extend the Unity Android Activity
2. How To Use Android Plugins in Unity Apps
3. How To Add Views Over Unity for Android
4. How To Display Toast on Target Detection and Open Website

But nothing works.. Please guide me or send a link of a working sample

Comment: You should start by clarifying your problem more and also show us what you have tried or at least what you think the solution might be. Also, add appropriate tags (in this case you also need Unity).

Comment: I was not able to add the flag(unity). sorry, I'm a newbie...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really appreciate your efforts. But there is a very simple way to do this:

- Try this script

  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;

  ```
   public class ShowToast : MonoBehaviour {

       // Use this for initialization
       void Start () {
           MyShowToastMethod ();

       }

       string toastString;
       AndroidJavaObject currentActivity;

       public void MyShowToastMethod ()
       {
           if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
               showToastOnUiThread ("It Worked!");
           }
       }

       void showToastOnUiThread(string toastString){
           AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");

           currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
           this.toastString = toastString;

           currentActivity.Call ("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable (showToast));
       }

       void showToast(){
           Debug.Log ("Running on UI thread");
           AndroidJavaObject context = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");
           AndroidJavaClass Toast = new AndroidJavaClass("android.widget.Toast");
           AndroidJavaObject javaString=new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String",toastString);
           AndroidJavaObject toast = Toast.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("makeText", context, javaString, Toast.GetStatic<int>("LENGTH_SHORT"));
           toast.Call ("show");
       }

   }
  ```

Comment: Can I change the text color & background color in this method?

Answer (score 0):

I am using unity extension but i m pretty sure core codabase is the same. Image target uses the class called DefaultTrackableEventHandler and there is OnTrackingFound() function. This is called once the image is detected so you can implement your message in there! This is how I do it anyways. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the help...

Now, I'm able to display toast message on image detection..

I have to create an Android app which is connected to a server, say Apache.

When an image is scanned i have to retrieve the data from the server according to the image scanned.

I wrote plugin in java and invoked them in script.. I can follow the same method, but how would I link the database with the image target.?? please help

Comment: Isnt vuforia cloud service doing this for you? I did not understand the question. Btw if my answer above solved your problem please mark it as an answer. Thank you

Comment: **Scenario**
Consider there is a database containing the details of the students.. And I have the ID card of the students as dataset.

**Desired Output**

When scanning an Image target I need to fetch the details of the particular student. If I scan the ID card of the student say "x", I need to fetch the all the relevant details about the student "x" from the database??

How can this be done? Does the thing which I ask is offered by Vuforia Cloud service?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Remember that, all I have to do this on Android bro... Btw, do you understand my question or still u don't catch??

Comment: Yes you can. It is basically online image target manager. You can add or modify data on them . Also you can add more targets online.

Comment: If I run the Cloud Recognition sample from Unity core samples or if I run Books sample it is saying that the key is missing... Even if I paste my own client access key and secret key it says that key is missing.. How does this works? I mean, do every cloud database have separate keys? Please help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: When the cloud target is detected in Vuforia, I have to launch new activity and display the metadata in textview.. This can be implemented using plugins right? But where do I call the method in vuforia?? Pls help.. Thanks in advance