# How to show a Google Play Games "Welcome Back" toast for android on Unity3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, toast, google-play-games

I'm already using the official plugin, logging in for the first time works perfectly and we can see the "Welcome + username" with a little avatar message popping up.

However, I do not see the "Welcome back" message that supposedly should appear whenever the user logs in silently (not showing a login prompt). In some games such as Crossy Road you do get the "Welcome" popup if the user silently logs in.

A little example of what I am doing using minimal code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GooglePlayGames;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GooglePlayLogic : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start ()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
        SilentSignIn();
    }

    public void SilentSignIn()
    {
        if (!PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.localUser.authenticated)
        {
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate ((bool success) => {
                if (success) {
                     //some code here
                 } else {
                    //some code here
                 }
            }, true); //true means no login prompt will show up
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Already signed in");
        }
    }
}
```

However, the normal "Welcome" popup always shows up if the user manually logs out and then logs in again. The issue here is that no message is showing up after the silent log in. What do I do for that to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. You have to call Android's native toast method.

Try this: *[Toast on Image Detection in Vuforia either using Unity or Java without C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35503237/toast-on-image-detection-in-vuforia-either-using-unity-or-java-without-c/37802042#37802042)*

Answer (score 0):

The silent login is usually, well, silent.  The underlying authentication flow only shows the welcome toast if it has been some time since it was shown, or as you pointed out, when the sign in process is after explicitly calling sign out.

Other than being noticeable and a little unsettling during testing, I am curious why want you it shown each time the game activity is resumed (or created)?

Comment: To answer to your last paragraph: It's part of their branding guidelines. https://developers.google.com/games/services/branding-guidelines#required-popups

Comment: Thanks for the response! "Ensure the 'Welcome back' pop-up is shown after sign-in and never interrupted by other game or player activities." is I think what you are referring to.  I appreciate the effort and intent to do align with these!  I believe this is talking more about trying to hide or obstruct something during sign-in, vs. it showing up all the time.